# Lookup values with different column names in pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
Name   No
A      1
A      2
B      5

Player Gender
A      F
B      M
C      F
```

I would like to create a new column `sex` in the `df1` dataframe, using corresponding values from the column `gender` in `df2`. The columns used to look up are `Name` in `df1` and `Player` in `df2`.

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `df2` where is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.set_index.html) from column `Player`:

```
df1['sex'] = df1.Name.map(df2.set_index('Player')['Gender'])
print (df1)
  Name  No sex
0    A   1   F
1    A   2   F
2    B   5   M
```

This is same as `map` by `dict`:

```
d = df2.set_index('Player')['Gender'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': 'F', 'B': 'M', 'C': 'F'}
df1['sex'] = df1.Name.map(d)
print (df1)
  Name  No sex
0    A   1   F
1    A   2   F
2    B   5   M
```

Or:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='Name', right_on='Player')
         .rename(columns={'Gender':'sex'})
         .drop('Player', axis=1))

  Name  No sex
0    A   1   F
1    A   2   F
2    B   5   M
```

First is more faster:

```
In [46]: %timeit (pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='Name', right_on='Player').rename(columns={'Gender':'sex'}).drop('Player', axis=1))
The slowest run took 4.53 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit df1.Name.map(df2.set_index('Player')['Gender'])
The slowest run took 4.78 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 882 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Is there any way to just create a colum `sex` in df1 instead of merging the 2 dataframes because the real df2 I have has many columns so I have to remove quite a lot of unused columns